# Bigquery client for Go much slower than the GUI (seconds vs milliseconds)

Tags: go, google-bigquery

```
    q := i.client.Query(query)

    job, err := q.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        <handle>
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        <handle>
    }
    if err = status.Err(); err != nil {
        <handle>
    }

    it, err := job.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        <handle>
    }
```

This is the code that I use to query a table in BigQuery. The `client` field is of the `*bigquery.Client` type.

The query itself is super simple like:

```
SELECT field, another_field from some_table LIMIT K OFFSET N
```

(I know that type of pagination isn't a best practice for BQ, but that's a subject for a separate discussion).

This `Run` call takes 2-4 seconds as compared to a few hundred milliseconds when querying in the GUI.

What could be wrong here? The official package documentation uses more or less the same approach to interact with BigQuery (sometimes they skip the `Wait` part though)

EDIT:

It turns out that using just `Query.Read()` is much faster: 1s instead of 3-4s with job waiting.
That said, it's still much slower than the GUI :)

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT, I have opened a ticket but my initial thought was that I could be doing something wrong and it's not an issue with BigQuery or the Go client :)

Comment: As initial troubleshooting it would be helpful to identify which part of code is actually taking the most time, either by manual time-diff calculation or using go-profiling

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between `Query.Read()` and `job.Read()` in the example you've provided, because it's the same mechanic (check source code https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/bigquery/v1.43.0/bigquery/query.go#L370). `Query.Read()` invokes `job.Run()` and then `job.Read()`

Main difference between go client for bigquery and GUI, I assume, is the way data is being read: in go client results are being read using rest API which fetches the results paginated (need to find the max page size but it's quite small because of http nature). And GUI seems to use the storage API ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage), [api docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries)) which is magnitude faster. If you're fetching large amount of data then difference will be significant.

Having a Gigabit connection throughput for my tests via go client was about 2MB/s and with storage API about 30MB/s.

Sorry for not providing complete reference links (because it takes too much time to collect them all) but I hope, I've pointed you the direction to read about bigquery throughput performance.

Another potential moment which may reduce the performance of bigquery is the priority (https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#QueryConfig). But it's interactive by default and if you haven't set it by yourself to `BatchPriority` then it's not the cause.

```golang
    // Priority specifies the priority with which to schedule the query.
    // The default priority is InteractivePriority.
    // For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#batchqueries
    Priority QueryPriority
```